# HTML 5 Audio Custom Control

Tags: javascript, audio, mp3

Seems like the paused property of the control is always true. I want one button to play/pause.  It will play audio, but not pause on the click event.

I want the button to play when clicked first time, then pause when I click again.  There would be many tracks as the audio control would need to use the data-song value to feed the source of the audio control.  Anytime I code to check the data-song it will not pause.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <script>

function playAudio()
{

var audio = document.getElementById('player');
var playbutton = document.getElementById('play');
var url = playbutton.getAttribute('data-song');

player.src = url;

if(audio.paused){


    audio.play();
    }
    else
    {
    audio.pause();
    }


}

</script>
</head>


<body>



<p id="play" onClick="playAudio()" data-song="rock.mp3" >play</p>






<audio controls id="player">
  <source src="" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time your function is called it sets the source of the audio again and
its default state is 'paused'. Put the source attribute in the audio tag like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>  
<title>Test</title>
<script>
function playPause()
{

 var audio = document.getElementById('player')
 var playbutton = document.getElementById('play')
 audio.controls = false

if(audio.paused){

  audio.play()
  playbutton.innerHTML = "stop"

}
else
{
  audio.pause()
  playbutton.innerHTML = "play"
}  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="play" onClick="playPause()" >play</p>
<audio id="player" src="lala.mp3"></audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to use different sources. I should've explained in the original post and will edit.  There would be many track listings with a play button by it. I wanted to send the track file reference to the audio control.

Comment: Have a look at the DOM reference for the audio tag. You can use the ondended event to change the source.